# URI object behaivor with encdoded string

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, visual-studio

I'm creating COM visible library containing class with IDTExtensibility2 interface to use it as Add-In for Microsoft VBA Editor for Microsoft Excel. Sending GET request with HttpClient inside. My request contain encoded string ("/" replaced with "%2F", "." with "%2E" and etc.) but response contains error. More investigations show that looks like input Uri with type string for method GetAsync converted to object System.URI (I can also use it directly for GetAsync – same result) and my encoded Uri string became converted to non-encoded version after creation of System.URI object ("%2F" replaced with "/", "%2E" with "."  and etc.) or request execution.

I've found some information that System.URI works faulty in that way for .Net Framework below 4.5.
Doesn't matter what version I choose in project properties – it works same way. I was trying 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6 (with version 3.5 I cannot compile library because of some missed classes).
Also tried to get version of System.URI during runtime inside of my library with `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(typeof(Uri).Assembly.Location).ProductVersion` and getting version 4.7.3416.0 (new one).

But when I created testing console app with .Net version 3.5 System.URI class (Product version 2.0.50727.8806 old one) works same way like in my COM library inside VBA Editor! After that, I found out that Microsoft Office software requirement is .NET Framework version 3.5 or higher (I’m using Office 2013). Looks like my Add-In uses System reference of MS Office application, not my project settings.

I tried to define alias for System reference in using section of my library .cs file and use this alias for all System.* classes inside it – result is the same. Also tried to check some reference settings for System reference like “Copy local” and “Embed Interop Types” – nothing changes.

`Uri testuri = new Uri("http://testuri/TestWbk%2FModule1%2Ebas");`

.NET Framework 3.5 result:

`testuri.AbsoluteUri = "http://testuri/TestWbk/Module1.bas"`

.NET Framework 4.5 result (need that, non-encoded dot is nevermind):

`testuri.AbsoluteUri = "http://testuri/TestWbk%2FModule1.bas"`